# moment.js date format not working in iOS

Tags: jquery, date, momentjs

I have an app built with JQuery Mobile & PhoneGap, and this code isn't working in iOS but works perfectly for android. I am also using moment.js

> format for date = Thu Sep 17 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)

```
var selecdate = new Date(date).getTime(); //Get the Unix time based on date selected from calender
var sDate = moment(selecdate); //pass the date to the moment.js library
var aDate = moment();//Get current date
var PTime = sDate.diff(aDate, 'days');//Calculate the different between current date and selected date using moment.js library.


if (PTime < 0){ //If the selected date is before today return false.
alert("Select a Future Date");
return false;
}
```

Can someone help here? Not sure why this simple code isn't working in iOS. In Android if the user selects any date that's before today's date PTime would be less than O and it would alert the user to 'Select a Future Date' in iOS it completely ignores the if statement.

Comment: What is an example value of the `date` variable in the first line?  And please elaborate what you mean by "it's not working".

Comment: in Android if user selects date that's before today it returns false after the alert 'Select a Future Date' in iOS it completely skips that if statement. It seems like it doesn't like the date format.

Comment: Please be clear is `date` a *string* with that exact formatting including the time zone abbreviation? or is it a `Date` object?  What does `typeof date` return?  And if it's a `Date` object, then why are you creating another `Date` object from it?  Really, you can just pass it directly to the moment constructor:  `sdate = moment(date)` - There's no need to go through `Date` and `getTime`.

Comment: Also, I'm fairly certain it's not ignoring the `if` statement.  Instead it's likely you've errored and halted execution somewhere before then.  You may want to consider remote debugging (see [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) or [here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/debugging_remote_debugging_tools.md.html)) as a technique to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Lastly, since `diff` is only going to consider whole 24-hour days, you may wish to instead do something like `if (moment(date).isBefore(moment().startOf('day')))`

Comment: date is a date object, and you are right it's not ignore the if but for some reason iOS dosn't like the date format. PTime is not valid in iOS but is valid for Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of `new Date(dateObject)` is not defined by the ECMAScript spec.  In most cases, it will be equivalent to `new Date(dateObject.valueOf())`, which is equivalent to the original `dateObject`.  I'm not 100% positive but it's possible that some environments (such as older Android devices) may not have implemented that.  If it's not implemented, your code might be stopping on the very first line.

Besides, it's completely unnecessary.  You can just do:

```
if (moment(date).isBefore(moment().startOf('day'))) {
    alert("Select a Future Date");
    return false;
}
```

Or you can even do this without moment, like so:

```
function getStartOfToday() {
    var dt = new Date();

    dt.setHours(0);
    dt.setMinutes(0);
    dt.setSeconds(0);
    dt.setMilliseconds(0);  

    // Handle browser-specific DST edge case when day starts at 1:00 AM
    // Ex: Firefox on Oct 18, 2015 in Brazil
    if (dt.getHours() !== 0) {
        dt.SetTime(dt.getTime() + 36e5);
    }

    return dt;
}

var today = getStartOfToday();
if (date < today) {
    alert("Select a Future Date");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thx, let me test this on iOS. How do I solve the new Date(dateObject) issue if I have to set the date and time myself and compare to current time. ex `var rdate = moment(fordate).format('YYYY MM DD');  var rtdate = moment(rdate+" "+ctime);`

Comment: I guess the question is how do I get pass that if this is the format of the date Thu Sep 17 2015 15:00:00 GMT-0400. Or should I change the format?

Comment: Read [the docs on string parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)